# php-fpm: unrecognized service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php-fpm, php5

I can't seem to `restart` my `php fpm` on my Ubuntu server

I did

**ps aux | grep php-fpm**

I got

```
root      1543  0.0  0.7 444672  7552 ?        Ss   Nov10   2:14 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
forge     1587  0.0  4.3 687152 43728 ?        S    Nov10   9:47 php-fpm: pool www
forge     3443  0.0  2.8 458504 28784 ?        S    Nov10   9:44 php-fpm: pool www
root      3569  0.0  0.0  14520   932 pts/0    S+   21:36   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
forge    26548  0.0  2.5 451148 25884 ?        S    Nov21   0:26 php-fpm: pool www
```

---

Then when I tried

**sudo service php-fpm restart**

> php-fpm: unrecognized service.

How do I prevent that ?

Comment: Why didn't you include the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On ubuntu, I believe the command is:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

You can find the service name by doing:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep -i fpm
```

Comment: Yep, or `php7-fpm` or `php7.0-fpm` if you're on v7.